# Search multiple fields from one text box in a View

Tags: views, search

I have a database of articles with some taxonomies to classify each article. I also have a view that also contains a faceted search and uses filters to create dropdowns for the taxonomy fields using Views (see the image below). The search results will show facets in the sidebar and a user can click on them to further refine results (such as facets like Doc Year, Doc Author, etc.) The problem is that I really only need one text box to search a group of 3 text fields in this View.

For example, each article contains these three separate text fields:

- Article Title
- Article Title in French
- Article Body

I want one text box on the search form to search these three fields without having to create three fields, one for each database field. The rest of the dropdowns to search each taxonomy can exist in the form to appear like below.

Thank you to everyone helping think how to accomplish this. I am sure it has been done before many times.

[image: Simple Search Example]

Comment: did you try ` Global: Combine fields filter`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve it by using  `Global: combine field filter`.
For details and get familiar with it take a look at

https://swsblog.stanford.edu/blog/views-exposed-filters-multiple-field-search

Comment: The problem received back about the solution is this: we are working with a search Index and can not combine fields from exposed filter.